# Javascript string manipulations

Tags: javascript, string

I want to manipulate the javascript.

```
var url = "AND from:3035554570 AND to:52894565";
```

If the first word of url is `"AND"` i want to remove that and get the remaining part as my output.

i.e. `url = "from:3035554570 AND to:52894565";`

and if the first word is not `"AND"` then keep the url as it is.

Comment: Can you please provide a valid example? This is not valid JavaScript. Do you mean `var url = "And from:3035554570 AND to:52894565";`? (also this doesn't appear to be a URL).

Comment: Simple regex will do it.

Comment: `AND` and `And` are not the same.

Comment: @alex Heck, a simple `substr` would do...

Comment: @Felix I am creating a string which will be passed as a part of URL

Comment: It's still not valid code ;)

Comment: `substr` would replace all occurances, you need to anchor to the beginning of the string with regex

Comment: @deceze harsh words!

Comment: @alex It's a hard world. :-P

Comment: @deceze Doh! I misread that - but while using substr would work that way (so why not post it as an answer for people to read?), I'd be interested in seeing the performance difference if you wanted to do a jsperf, plus I think that it's slightly less easily readable due to the fixed length - easily changed, but needs a longer answer for discussions on it  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of a regular expression, the `^` locks it to the start of the string, the `\s+` means one or more space characters, so this will replace it if found, otherwise it'll do nothing.

```
url = url.replace(/^And\s+/, "");
```

If the `"And"` can be any case then use an `i` on the end or the regex to make it case insensitive:

```
url = url.replace(/^And\s+/i, "");
```

Comment: But i want to remove the "AND" at the start of the string only.

Comment: That's what the `^` on the front is, it's an anchor, and means that it'll only match from the beginning of the string.

Comment: @user3177493: Read the answer carefully.